# What tool do you suggest me for making a painting catalog?

Tags: software-recommendation, design

I have taken some photos of my paintings so I would like to make a catalog of them.

Edited.

It is for both, digital and printing distribution.

I'd want to promote my art by making a catalog of them.

I never used some application for design but I want to get started with one.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Are you looking to create a catalog for printing? Digital distribution? Can you provide more detail regarding what it is that you want? Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely recommend Scribus, it is the best open source desktop publishing software. It is really the best fit for this task.

Answer (score 0):

I use Gimp image editor or Inkscape for importing/exporting/editing. For catalogue-ing, I would use LibreOffice Impress or LaTeX editors like

http://www.sharelatex.com

http://www.scribtex.com/

or VIM/Kile

Comment: Mentioning LaTeX, I think TeXStudio is the best edit around, however I don't think OP would need it for the task at hand.